# Drawing waveform for wav audio in Android

Tags: java, android, audio, pcm, waveform

My android application needs to draw Waveform for the audio recorded as raw pcm using         [AudioRecord](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html) class.
I went through the source code of opensource project [RingDroid](http://code.google.com/p/ringdroid/) , which shows waveform and process audio in android, but i couldn't understand anything as it is complicated one.

Please show me some code that draw waveform from pcm data.

Comment: @donfede Have a look at this  http://codeidol.com/java/swing/Audio/Build-an-Audio-Waveform-Display/

Comment: thx - yep, I've a working solution built upon Ringdroid.  You should select an answer for this Q ;)

Comment: did you find a solution

Comment: @donfededid you find a solution

Answer (score 2):

There is an Android class called Visualizer that lets you access audio.

Visualizer can not only access the "live" audio output mix but also the audio from a particular MediaPlayer or AudioTrack

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Visualizer.html

There is a live wallpaper that uses Visualizer to show the audio output mix but this could be adapted to use audio from a MediaPlayer or AudioTrack
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/wallpapers/MusicVisualization/+/master/src/com/android/musicvis

Comment: Does anyone understand what the Visualizer shows? I fail to see anything information in those animations, as opposed to a proper waveform.